# Memory modules not running at rated speeds

Tags: memory, motherboard, overclocking

I'm having some odd memory issues with my build. Here are my specifications right now:

- QDI Superb 4 motherboard
- Intel Pentium 4 Northwood 2.4 GHz (512 KB L2, 533 MHz FSB)
- 3x 256 MB PC2100 DDR266 RAM
- 16 MB NVIDIA TNT2 Pro AGP
- Seagate 80 GB IDE HDD
- Generic USB 2.0 PCI
- Generic Modem PCI
- Bestec 250 W PSU

To be even more specific, here are the current brands and models of each module:

- Kingston KVR266X64C25/256
- Samsung PC2100U-25331-Z
- SMART SM5643285D4N0CHM0H

Supposedly, they are all PC2100 266 MHz modules with a latency of 2.5. Looking in Speccy, the Kingston module is somehow running at a speed of PC2300 ~284 MHz. I've never overclocked RAM at all as I don't know how to.

However, when I first started the computer, I had the SMART module in place first and then reset the BIOS settings, including the integrated overclocking options. However, this still doesn't explain why the Kingston module runs at a higher speed than the SMART and Samsung module.

Why is it like this? On a side note, where could I find the motherboard manual for the QDI Superb 4?

Comment: How did you confirm that the Kingston memory was running at 284 MHz?

Comment: I just looked up in Speccy. I don't know how else I would be able to directly find out whether it was running faster or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This still doesn't explain why the
>   Kingston module runs at a higher speed
>   than the SMART and Samsung module.

Confirm this is correct, by using [CPU-z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) and checking the speeds of each memory stick

Comment: CPU-Z and SIW is reading that the Kingston module is PC2300 (142 MHz) DDR but can run at PC2100 (133 MHz) but with a CAS latency of 2 instead of 2.5. For the Samsung and SMART modules, they run at PC2100 (133 MHz) with CAS 2.5. I'm just guessing that all modules will try to run at the same CAS latency first, then at the same speed. I was getting an occasional BSOD on startup as well, probably meaning that the RAM isn't configured well.

Comment: @Wes : BSODs indicate mismatch of timings, can you enter the BIOS and change latencies of all sticks to the same ?

Comment: I think there is an option for that. However, if I set the latencies of all modules to the same, the Kingston module will be running at a different speed. Would that not cause problems?

Comment: @Wes AFAIK Memory modules sync themselves to the same speed, ie, the speed which is common to all. Setting the latencies should not cause any problems.

Comment: I don't have an option to set latency but I just set the speed to 266MHz and it seems to have no problems. Another issue right now is finding chipset drivers because I have IDE controller errors... Thanks!